# What are the system fonts of Firefox OS?

Tags: firefox-os

[Fira Sans](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/styleguide/products/firefox-os/typeface/) seems to be the default font, but I'm wondering what other fonts are on the device that can be used by apps via CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file describes the fonts that are installed in Firefox OS: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/moztt/blob/master/fonts.mk. This is for the master branch. Check the other branches in the git repository to find out about fonts available in a specific Firefox OS version.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this site for the different typeface supported by firefox os https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/styleguide/products/firefox-os/typeface/